# Multi tenant configuration spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, multi-tenant, dependency-properties

I wonder if there is a good solution to manage different configurations for different tenants in runtime, the same instance should manage all the tenants.

Currently, the application gets all the properties using @Value but this inject the properties in the application runs, and the property is gonna be different depends on the tenant making the request.